# Livepatch enable not found?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, canonical-livepatch

machine is running Xenial, updated from Wily using do-dist-upgrade

Trying to set up live patching as an experiment before apply to my seedbox (a different machine)

Following these instructions
cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-live-patch-ubuntu-linux-server-kernel-without-rebooting/

```
~$ canonical-livepatch status
Machine is not enabled. Please run 'sudo canonical-livepatch enable' with the
token obtained from https://ubuntu.com/livepatch.

~$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable [key]
sudo: canonical-livepatch: command not found
```

Please advise.

Comment: That's odd. Does `sudo $(which canonical-livepatch) enable [key]` work?

Comment: Is the canonical-livepatch snap installed properly and working? `snap list` will show you the installed snaps and you can verify that the service is running by `systemctl status snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did have the same error message, log files did not help me either. 
So I did as root:

```
snap remove canonical-livepatch
apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

afterwards again as root:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch 
sudo canonical-livepatch enable **your token here**
```

output was: Successfully enabled device. Using machine-token: your token here
:)

Comment: Yeah, same thing worked here- basically just  wiping it and starting over. No idea why it worked the second time but not the first. I guess "uninstall and try again" is the software equivalent of "try restarting it" lol

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
"sudo pro enable livepatch"
to enable livepatch service.

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs because the path, /snap/bin, is not in the search path used by sudo. Obviously, it is in the path when you are a regular user. The simple solution is to use the full path when running the command as a superuser,

sudo /snap/bin/canonical-livepatch enable **your token here**