# sudo: canonical-livepatch: command not found

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

I am trying to install canonical-livepatch to update software on ubuntu.

I did everything mentioned in this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849904/livepatch-enable-not-found).

I did reboot machine. But still I am facing error.

> Warning: /snap/bin was not found in your $PATH. If you've not
>   restarted your
>            session since you installed snapd, try doing that. Please see
>            https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/9469 for more details.

Any help, any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found some list of commands to make it work.

Below are the list of commands followed by steps in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849904/livepatch-enable-not-found).

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

Make sure /snap/bin in your PATH, run:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin' >> ~/.bashrc

# Load the file
source ~/.bashrc

#Verify path
echo "$PATH"
```

Now, enable the service with your token. The syntax is:

```
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable {YOUR-TOKEN-HERE}
```

So if token was d3b07384d213edec49eaa6238ad5ff00, enter:

```
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable d3b07384d213edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
```

Sample outputs:

```
Successfully enabled device. Using machine-token: d3b07384d213edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
```

**View status**

Type the following command to view kernel’s livepatch status:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
```

Sample outputs:

```
kernel: 4.4.0-43.63-generic
fully-patched: true
version: ""
```

My kernel is fully patched. You can pass the --verbose option to see more details:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status --verbose
```

Source [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-live-patch-ubuntu-linux-server-kernel-without-rebooting/).